# why this role does not have permission for this action in QNA Maker

Tags: permissions, azure-qna-maker

I receive this role does not have permission for this action. WHen I try to add a Azure QnA Service.Not sure how to get around it

Comment: what are you saying?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 6):

- Go to access control (IAM) blade of your qnamaker service in azure portal
- Add role assignment
- Select Cognitive Service QnA Maker Editor Role
- Select the identity you are using to log on to qnamaker.ai
- Save

This will resolve the issue and you should be able to select your qnamaker service.

Answer (score 4):

Recreate one from the QnAMaker page, then once you created it, refresh the whole page (not by clicking Refresh Button on the current QnAMaker.ai/Create page).

If that doesn't work, delete the current QnAMaker service, recreate it, and do the above process.

It worked for me.

Comment: "refresh the whole page (not by clicking Refresh Button on the current QnAMaker.ai/Create page)" --secret magic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to access control (IAM) and add a role assigment.
First you need to select owner and your assignemt access (Azure AD user, group, or application. Then, the identity that you are using to log on to qnamaker.ai and save.
By the end, repeat all the before process, but instead of owner you must select contributor and save. Refresh the page and Voil`a ;)