# Can't create ms azure bot

Tags: azure, service, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am having an account on Microsoft azure with GitHub student verification. As per show in azure tutorials i tried to create a bot. I went to QnA maker and successfully created a service in step 1. But in step 2  Azure QnA service is showing that this role does not have permission to perform this action. I am sharing a screenshot of a page.[image]

Please guide me further what's the problem here...

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why this role does not have permission for this action in QNA Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001975/why-this-role-does-not-have-permission-for-this-action-in-qna-maker)

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I can't find the access control panel

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AvoaxdL Because I don't want to put  this into an answer until the solution is found